# Front end for editing drop down list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I think I am having an issue with terminology.

I have a situation where I have a database holding values in a table to be used in a select drop down in a web front end. Currently have a SQL Server database and using ColdFusion with JavaScript (mostly jQuery). To be honest I was surprised when I couldn't find a quick and easy jQuery solution to this.

I am looking for a way to offer an end user the ability to add to the list of values available in that drop down list.

Now I could manually build this, but I had the feeling that this is something that has been tackled before and sexier than I could write code must already exist. My searches however have been fruitless as I keep running into the very standard question of how to populate a front end select drop down with values from a table.

Can anyone point me towards a slick system of allowing an end user to update a list of values? Or if you know the terminology I need to be able to find this ability I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a little unclear as to which of the following two questions you are asking:

1) How to build select options (a drop-down list0 with values from a table.

2) How to create an interface to manage values in a table.

These are two distinct problems to solve. I *believe* you are more interested in knowing the answer to question 2, **how to create an interface for updating a table:**

It really depends on what kind of experience you want your user to have... who is the person (people) who need to update this list of values?  Do you need to have authentication (user/password) to manage the table?

A simple but not sexy solution is to give them access to a web data administrator program such as phpmyadmin (for mysql), [or perhaps this one for SQL Server.](http://sqlwebadmin.codeplex.com/)

Other than that, you are really looking to create an application, so any framework or set of tools that lets you interface with the database of choice is good. A term to search for is "CRUD" which stands for Create Read Update Delete, typically associated with simple applications.

Try this search for [simple crud application](https://www.google.com/search?q=simple%20crud%20application&rct=j)

Comment: Apologies that I was unclear. I was most definitely meaning to be in the question two camp. I was hoping that someone would know a built application / user interface for managing the updating of a list. I need to allow people with little to no experience databases to update. So good shout on the CRUD application. I'm not looking for the ability which I can already build, I was more looking for examples of the user interface for a CRUD application and how I can present a slick system for updating a list of values. I'm starting to see a few front ends so thanks for the tip.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you are starting to find a couple of options.  If it were me solving your exact problem, I would use: [laravel administrator](http://administrator.frozennode.com/).  That's a package for Laravel (a php MVC framework) that makes the front-end for "administration" in an application very easy to build/configure.

Comment: Since you are using ColdFusion, it looks like there is a package that could accomplish something similar: [crack](https://github.com/joshknutson/crack).  A good CSS framework to make everything **look good** is [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)